# I can't compile a react app because of lack of webpack and react scripts

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to compile a react app made by other person, after making a npm i I had the following errors

```
PS C:\Users\valery\Desktop\SemWebApp\PTS-WEB-APP-master> npm run start
> demo1@7.1.7 start C:\Users\valery\Desktop\SemWebApp\PTS-WEB-APP-master
> react-scripts start -o

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'webpack'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\valery\Desktop\SemWebApp\PTS-WEB-APP-master\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\lib\Server.js
- C:\Users\valery\Desktop\SemWebApp\PTS-WEB-APP-master\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\valery\Desktop\SemWebApp\PTS-WEB-APP-master\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\lib\Server.js:33:17)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19) {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: [
'C:\\Users\\valery\\Desktop\\SemWebApp\\PTS-WEB-APP-master\\node_modules\\webpack-dev- 
server\\lib\\Server.js',
'C:\\Users\\valery\\Desktop\\SemWebApp\\PTS-WEB-APP-master\\node_modules\\react- 
scripts\\scripts\\start.js'
]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! demo1@7.1.7 start: `react-scripts start -o`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the demo1@7.1.7 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\valery\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-05T22_44_12_999Z-debug.log
```

after I've installed webpack in the followng way and has its results

```
PS C:\Users\valery\Desktop\SemWebApp\PTS-WEB-APP-master> npm install webpack --save-dev
npm WARN @material-ui/pickers@3.2.10 requires a peer of @date-io/core@^1.3.6 but none is installed. 
You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN bootstrap@4.5.0 requires a peer of jquery@1.9.1 - 3 but none is installed. You must install 
peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN css-loader@2.1.1 requires a peer of webpack@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install 
peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-loader@3.0.2 requires a peer of webpack@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must 
install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN file-loader@3.0.1 requires a peer of webpack@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install 
peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN html-webpack-plugin@4.0.0-beta.5 requires a peer of webpack@^4.0.0 but none is installed. 
You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN mini-css-extract-plugin@0.8.0 requires a peer of webpack@^4.4.0 but none is installed. You 
must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin@5.0.3 requires a peer of webpack@^4.0.0 but none is 
installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN sass-loader@7.2.0 requires a peer of webpack@^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 but none is installed. You 
must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN style-loader@1.0.0 requires a peer of webpack@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install 
peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN terser-webpack-plugin@1.4.1 requires a peer of webpack@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You 
must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tsutils@3.18.0 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 
3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none 
is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN url-loader@2.1.0 requires a peer of webpack@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install 
peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN webpack-cli@3.3.11 requires a peer of webpack@4.x.x but none is installed. You must install 
peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN webpack-dev-server@3.2.1 requires a peer of webpack@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must 
install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN webpack-manifest-plugin@2.1.1 requires a peer of webpack@2 || 3 || 4 but none is installed. 
You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN workbox-webpack-plugin@4.3.1 requires a peer of webpack@^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 but none 
is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.0.7 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.0.7: wanted 
{"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\jest-haste- 
map\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted 
{"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 
(node_modules\watchpack\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted 
{"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 
(node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted 
{"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ webpack@5.11.1
added 46 packages from 96 contributors in 248.834s

98 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details
```

and finally I tried to make a npm run start with the following results

PS C:\Users\valery\Desktop\SemWebApp\PTS-WEB-APP-master> npm run start

> demo1@7.1.7 start C:\Users\valery\Desktop\SemWebApp\PTS-WEB-APP-master
> react-scripts start -o
> Starting the development server...
> Failed to compile.

TypeError: Cannot read property 'tapAsync' of undefined

- ExternalModuleFactoryPlugin.js:41 ExternalModuleFactoryPlugin.apply
  [PTS-WEB-APP-master]/[webpack]/lib/ExternalModuleFactoryPlugin.js:41:39
- ExternalsPlugin.js:30
  [PTS-WEB-APP-master]/[webpack]/lib/ExternalsPlugin.js:30:63
- Hook.js:154 SyncHook.lazyCompileHook
  [PTS-WEB-APP-master]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:154:20
- Compiler.js:665
  [PTS-WEB-APP-master]/[react-scripts]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:665:23
- Hook.js:154 AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook
  [PTS-WEB-APP-master]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:154:20
- Compiler.js:662 Compiler.compile
  [PTS-WEB-APP-master]/[react-scripts]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:662:28
- Compiler.js:328 Compiler.runAsChild
  [PTS-WEB-APP-master]/[react-scripts]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:328:8
- compiler.js:129
  [PTS-WEB-APP-master]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/compiler.js:129:21
- new Promise
- compiler.js:128 HtmlWebpackChildCompiler.compileTemplates
  [PTS-WEB-APP-master]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/compiler.js:128:31
- compiler.js:260 Object.compileTemplate
  [PTS-WEB-APP-master]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/compiler.js:260:24
- index.js:149
  [PTS-WEB-APP-master]/[html-webpack-plugin]/index.js:149:42
- Hook.js:154 AsyncParallelHook.lazyCompileHook
  [PTS-WEB-APP-master]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:154:20

and the app won't compile, how can I solve those problems?

I'm very very new to react and I don't know how to solve it

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: It looks like it might be an issue with the `html-webpack` plugin. Search up "TypeError: Cannot read property 'tapAsync' of undefined" and you'll find some people with similar issues and how they solved them

Comment: Did you install all project dependencies before running npm start? `npm install`

Comment: Hi @Benjamin, yes, the npm install was the first thing I did, after that came the problem with webpack, then I did a npm install webpack --save-dev and now it gaves me the tapasync issue